# Find Version of Binary File

Tags: python, version, binaryfiles

Does anyone know how I can find the version of a binary file that has been passed to my function?

I got the following code from [this page](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/reading-binary-file-in-python-804296/):

```
def version(fpath):
    f = open(fpath, 'rb')

    s = f.read(1024)
    print s

    f.close()
```

However, this does not give me any useful output similar to what the mentioned website shows.

**Edit**: @BoazYaniv tells me that the file format plays in important part in this problem. This is a windows EXE file

Comment: Which kind of binary file? It all depends on the format, you know.

Comment: I didn't know that! How does the format affect the functionality?

Comment: Is your file a xft file? if not, that tutorial is irrelevant. But you can use it for an example of reading a specified amount of data from a binary file, edit it according to your format.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Because each binary file format stores its version in a different place and a different way - if at all.

Comment: Anyway, edit your question to include the format you want to parse. For now, I can suggest you to try out the `struct` module that comes with python. It's very useful for reading binary files. If you want something more powerful, there's a package called `construct` which is much more flexible, but you probably need much more experience about binary formats if you get to the stage you need it.

Comment: A windows EXE? Then the format is called [PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) (Portable Executable), which is in turn a variant of [COFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use this code to pull versions from one of our executables for use throughout other programs.

```
import win32api

try:
    info = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo('rpmsrv.exe', "\\")
    ms = info['FileVersionMS']
    ls = info['FileVersionLS']
    __version__ = "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (win32api.HIWORD(ms), win32api.LOWORD (ms),
                                 win32api.HIWORD (ls), win32api.LOWORD (ls))
except:
    __version__ = '5.1.1.000' # some appropriate default here.
```

--- To encompass the comments ---

This requires that the Windows Bindings for Python be installed.  They're available here:  http://starship.python.net/~skippy/win32/.  This also limits this solution to Windows platforms (which may or may not be an important factor in the final project).

Comment: Good alternatives, but you should add a note that this requires the Windows extensions for Python, and that it would only run on Windows (because it uses the Windows API instead of directly parsing the file).

Comment: @Boaz Yaniv - True statements.  I wasn't familiar with the utility from your answer and will have to do some reading.  Thanks!

Comment: It will also read the version form slightly different place in the PE (this structure is called VS_FIXEDFILEINFO in pefile). This is ok, but it may miss some string value that sometimes get added to the version information, because that structure allow only a 4 16-bit integer values (representing the version parts) instead of a free-form string.

Answer (score 12):

You have a ready-made module for parsing EXE files:
http://code.google.com/p/pefile/

You could read it using the following code:

```
import pefile

pe = pefile.PE(r'C:\Windows\notepad.exe')
FileVersion    = pe.FileInfo[0].StringTable[0].entries['FileVersion']
ProductVersion = pe.FileInfo[0].StringTable[0].entries['ProductVersion']
```

As you can see, Windows EXE (and DLL) files store two different kinds of versions, FileVersion and ProductVersion. Many times they are the same, but sometimes they may different - it all depends on the one who made the EXE really.

### Edit:

Just to make things more complex, these two strings in the PE string table aren't the only place where Windows compilers may save the version. There are two addiotnal FileVersion and ProductVersion values stored in the EXE, only they are stored as pairs of 32-bit integers, each of them is broken, in turn, into two 16-bit integers (WORDs in Windows API speak). Altogether, each version value (FileVersion and ProductVersion) has 4 16-bit WORDs which represent the dot-separated parts of the version. You can get them too, using pefile:

```
pe = pefile.PE(r'C:\Windows\notepad.exe')
FileVersionLS    = pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.FileVersionLS
FileVersionMS    = pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.FileVersionMS
ProductVersionLS = pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.ProductVersionLS
ProductVersionMS = pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.ProductVersionMS

FileVersion = (FileVersionMS >> 16, FileVersionMS & 0xFFFF, FileVersionLS >> 16, FileVersionLS & 0xFFFF)
ProductVersion = (ProductVersionMS >> 16, ProductVersionMS & 0xFFFF, ProductVersionLS >> 16, ProductVersionLS & 0xFFFF)

print 'File version:    %s.%s.%s.%s' % FileVersion 
print 'Product version: %s.%s.%s.%s' % ProductVersion
```

But wait! This is not all: you have at least one more place where you could look to find the version: Inside another structure, called OPTIONAL_HEADER, you can find another two values called MajorImageVersion and MinorImageVersion. They represent the two first parts of the whole version, so a file which has a ProductVersion or FileVersion of, say, 6.1.7600.150, would usually have a MajorImageVersion of 6 and a MinorImageVersion of 1. You could get them with `pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.MajorImageVersion` and `pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.MinorImageVersion`.

All these values (5 different ones, if I count them right) are usually equivalent (if you ignore the extra freeform string value the ones at a string table sometimes have), but its quite common to see FileVersions and ProductVersions that are not the same, and you should also be ready for other surprises as well.

Comment: +1 this is a really good hack. Sadly my manager wont let me use it

Comment: This answer has an advantage over the win32api. pefile module can be installed with pip eaily while pywin32 can't. User needs to download whl for pywin32 to install.

Comment: Slight ammendment, `pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.FileVersionLS` should be `pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO[0].FileVersionLS` and so forth. As they are lists. Might not have been true in this older version!

Comment: In addition of the slight amendment of @Rots, only "Edit" part works for me, both `pe.FileInfo[0].StringTable[0].entries['FileVersion']` and `pe.FileInfo[0].StringTable[0].entries['ProductVersion']` gives a `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'StringTable'` for me (python 3.10.5 and pefile 2022.5.30).