# Selenium Python quit() method not working from command line

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

Using python 3.6.2 and FF (geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64), I have a try/except block setup to close selenium upon any exceptions, which I'm expecting to close all instances of the FF browser opened by selenium. I have this code:

```
    while 1:

        try:

            print(now() + "    [+] GETTING OBJECT...")

            browser.get(url)

            obj = browser.find_element_by_class_name('search_result_row')

            objID = browser.execute_script(
                'return document.getElementsByClassName( '
                '"search_result_row" )[0].children[1].innerText.trim()')

            print("\nObject " + objID + " received @ " + now())

            objDSC = browser.execute_script(
                'return document.getElementsByClassName( '
                '"search_result_row" )[0].children[2].innerText.trim()')

            print('\n' + objDSC)

            for type in objTypes:
                print("CHECKING IF OBJECT IS: " + type + "...")
                if type in objDSC:
                    print("OBJECT IS OF USEABLE TYPE.")
                else:
                    print("OBJECT IS NOT OF USEABLE TYPE.\n")

            time.sleep(5)

        except:

            while(browser):
                print('Quitting browser...')
                browser.quit()
                time.sleep(3)

            sys.exit(0)
```

When I start the script from a command prompt using "python filename.py", I see 4x FF processes started in task manager, however upon an error or SIGINT, "Quitting browser..." just loops, as expected, but the 4x FF processes do not end (I've waited for several minutes, to be sure). I've also tried browser.close() before the quit() method with no luck. I'm not sure what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Comment: I've had a similar problem. I always end up going into activity monitor/task manager and close the process manually.

Comment: Update the question with the code block within `try{}` along with your binary versions

Comment: Perhaps by knowing the exception message might give us some insight?

Comment: @DebanjanB The code within the try{} simply parses the returned html for a key word and prints it out , it's really basic. And I have not compiled the program, simply running it from the command line.

Comment: @AldoSuwandi The script doesn't actually generate any exceptions, it works, I'm using the try/except as a means of catching a keyboard interrupt. I wrongfully assumed that, when run from the command line, a ctrl+c would not only stop the script, but would tell selenium/webdriver to close the existing browser instances as well.

Comment: @user2442072 The code within the `try{}` is required to analyze why `quit()` is not properly invoked. Your binary version details are expected too.

Comment: @DebanjanB I've updated the try{} block to include the contained code. I'm not sure how to acquire the binary version info you're asking for? Is this SO question the way to go? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996650/find-version-of-binary-file#5996750) ?

Comment: @user2442072 Binary version details as in Selenium/WebDriver/Browser variant & version info

Comment: @DebanjanB

Selenium: 3.11.0
Webdriver: geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64
Firefox: 59.0.2 (64-bit)